# form made only from images (with scroll bars)

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, iframe, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to make a page that allows users to select one shirt, one pair of pants, and a pair of shoes from an existing selection (horizontal scrollers for each group). The user then submits their selection and I receive an email of the users selection. Ideally the user should be able to see their complete selection either as an isolated element on the page or each scroller should focus on the chosen element.

I've been unsuccessful getting the selected element to display separately somewhere on the page.

As far as having three separate scrolling windows I was going to create three forms and put them in iframes, but it seems as though getting multiple forms to post with one submit button, and processing them is quite difficult.
I could scroll over all three groups simultaneously and this way keep it one form (shirts, pants, shoes) but this would be pretty ugly.

Here is a link to my scrolling form made from only one group. http://www.evan-livingston.com/test/list.php

I'm new to all of this, and I'll sacrifice some polish in order to get a working system.

What approach would be best to accomplish this system?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

more elegant looking suggestion (using only client side programming)

use forms and create a table with each element as part of TD or inline list

on click--> highlight the image

on double click--> push/append it to a new div with info(link, name etc) about image and do the needful in the form of anchors and list tags

this new div can be displayed now or on a click of a submit button as a list of selected items. add an anchor to remove an item on click.

well there can be many ways to go about it. this is just one way and avoid the pain of using php.

since u asked about approaches: i prefer client side programming to php but thats purely based on my experience. use jquery to help u move around with js.